# Is there a Spring Security default configuration file name?

Tags: spring, security

When Spring deals with configuration filenames, there are some defaults...

- When registering a DispatcherServlet in my web.xml, Spring looks up by default for a file named `<servletname>`-servlet.xml
- When registering a ContextLoadListener in my web.xml, Spring looks up by default for a file names applicationContext.xml

Therefore I ask: When I am using Spring Security, does Spring looks up a default filename? Or do I always have to configure it manually through `<context-param> <param-name> contextConfigLocation </param-name>filename</param-value></context-param>`...???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring Security doesn't have its own application context, it uses the one created by `ContextLoaderListener` (i.e. `applicationContext.xml`).

So, you should put your Spring Security configuration into `applicationContext.xml`, or, if you want to put into separate file, you need to import that file from `applicationContext.xml`:

```
<import resource = "security.xml" />
```

or declare it in addition to `applicationContext.xml` in `contextConfigLocatoion` `<context-param>`:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>applicationContext.xml, security.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Answer (score 0):

Spring roo does this:

- applicationContext.xml - root context
- applicationContext-security.xml - security config
- webmvc-config.xml - mvc/controllers etc